# How to create columns with Count and percentage using MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a data table below, I would like to create a query to produce a result table like below, with count and percentage, using MS Access Query. I am unable to create this.

```
Name
Alex
Alex
Bob
Bob
Roger
Tim
```

Below result table

```
 Name    Count Percentage
 Alex    2     33%
 Bob     2     33%
 Roger   1     16.6%
 Tim     1     16.6%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

SELECT Person, Count(Person) AS [Count], 100*(Count(Person)/DCount("*","T1")) AS Percentage
FROM T1
GROUP BY Person;